# CAF Error throw when chromecasting media with mpeg-cenc

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

[image: Error's screenshot]

Above is error's screenshot which described what I got when I try to chromecast one media whose format is mpeg-dash and ContentProtection is "Common Encryption"

It works well when I chromecasting mpeg-dash with Widevine or hls media.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you add your code from your post?

Comment: @jess thank you, the problem is the codecs of that media is not supported by Google Cast (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media)